seperating dictionary values by digits and letters
I'm trying to figure out how to take a dictionary value that contains digits and letters, split the digits from the letters, convert the digits to a float,  prompt the user for numerical input, add the users input to the digits in the value, then return the sum and the letters as a string to the  dictionary.
for example,
user_has = {'water': '16oz}
split 16oz into 16 and 'oz', add the users input of 1.3, then return '17.3oz' to the dictionary as the key's value.
I've tried several different methods that Ive found online, none seem to work for what Im trying to do though.

We could also do it in simple unnecessary long steps (deliberately for educational purpose):
from decimal import Decimal
import re

# pattern to split numeric and unit

pattern = r'(\d+\.?\d*)'
    

user_has = {'water': '16oz'}

# unpacks assumption: single value and unit
# e.g. 2.5km, 24mm, 7oz etc

_, numeric, units = re.split(pattern, user_has['water'])


# cast string numeric to Decimal due to floating issues : just being over careful 
numeric_ = Decimal(numeric)

# now we can add from user input
# say user input '1.5'
results = numeric_ + Decimal('1.5')

# upadte user_has
user_has['water'] = f'{float(results)}{units}'

print(user_has)

re split generates a list ['', numeric, unit], so we unpack only the last two.
Happy coding

You can use [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)? pattern for the number and (?i)[A-Z] pattern for the letters:
import re


def _update(d, key):
    val = d[key]
    digits = float(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', val)[0])
    letters = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z]', val))
    get_num = float(input("Enter an amount like 1.3: "))
    d[key] = str(digits + get_num) + letters
    return d


print(_update({'water': '16oz'}, 'water'))


Prints
{'water': '17.3oz'}
